# How do I use an already created object in one method in another?

Tags: java, class, object, methods

Alright so i created an instance of Game called game1 but how do I go about using the same instance of game1 in other methods? This is what I have so far

public static void main(String[] args)
    {

```
    int[] lotto1 = {3,11,15,27};
    int[] lotto2 = {11,14,18,21};
    int[] lotto3 = {9,22,29,30};
    int[] lotto4 = {1,7,13,22};
    int[] lotto5 = {11,21,22,30};
    ArrayList<Ticket> participants = new ArrayList<>();

    participants.add(new Ticket("Santos", "Dundalk", 899795253,lotto1));
    participants.add(new Ticket("Temi", "Balbriggan", 899795253, lotto2));
    participants.add(new Ticket("Miracle", "Dundalk", 899795253, lotto3));
    participants.add(new Ticket("Lateef", "Dublin", 899795253, lotto4));
    participants.add(new Ticket("Elijah", "Dundalk", 899795253, lotto5));

    Game game1 = new Game(participants);


}
public static void DisplayAllTickets()
{
    game1.displayAllTickets();
}
```

This is my Display all method in my Game class

```
 public void displayAllTickets()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ticket.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(ticket.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pass it as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `game1` object in other functions you could hand it to your function as a parameter.

```
public static void exampleFunction(Game game){
  //your function body where you do fancy stuff with your object
}
```

P.S
You can invoke the `displayAllTickets()` function directly on your `game1` object without adapter function `DisplayAllTickets()`.

```
game1.displayAllTickets();
```